rename files down to 3 characters then delete them if they are 6 mo old
I've pieced together this command from multiple places on the web, (most from here, thank you.)
Get-ChildItem -Path “\\$pc\c$\users\” -recurse -force | where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $(get-date).Adddays(-180)} | Rename-Item -NewName {
  $_.name.substring(0, [Math]::Min($_.BaseName.length, 3))} | rm -confirm:$false -ErrorAction ignore

I want it to rename all files to the first 3 characters, then delete them if they are older than 180. The command mostly works. But doesn't delete the files after wards. Once the command is done I can't do it again because the original files were modified so now they are less than 180 days old. Is there something I can change, or can I run a second command to delete all files that are 3 characters in length only?
Thank you.
****Update:
Thanks to @lit or user lit im not sure how to tag someone the answer was adding more to the path so it could be read.
Command with error/leaves files behind
Get-ChildItem -Path “\remotepc\c$\users\” -recurse -force | where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $(get-date).Adddays(-180)} | Remove-Item -recurse
Correct command
Get-ChildItem -Path “\?\UNC\remotepc\c$\users\” -recurse -force | where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $(get-date).Adddays(-180)} | Remove-Item -recurse
This commands deletes user files folders on a remote computer that have not been accessed for 6 months. And it reads file paths that exceed 260 characters to delete them as well.

Why do you need to rename them if you're going to delete them? Delete the files that are six months old (code for which you can find here already), and then rename the files that are left.

When i only use the delete command powershell does not delete all the files. There is a limit path mentioned here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell. The files I'm deleting exceed that limit.

If you can rename the files, you can delete the files. If the filename was too long to delete, it would also be too long to rename. And you're stuck if you don't delete first - as you said, the process of renaming them modifies them, which means they won't get deleted. You have to delete first.

unbeknownst to be me renaming the files works better than deleting them. Which is why i went with the rename files first, then delete. The problem is that after the files are renamed it changes the last write time to today so the files aren't deleted because they don't match the criteria of being older than 180 days.

Yes, I'm aware of that - I've explained it to you twice already. :-)

It is not clear why a file would be renamed before deletion, as @KenWhite suggested. The directory search should probably use the -File switch. The default for -Confirm on Remove-Item is already $false.
Will this be done to the 'All Users' and 'Default User' links? On my system, these point to C:\ProgramData and C:\Users\Default.
Get-ChildItem -Path “\\$pc\c$\users\” -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(-180) } |
    Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore


the $pc is a variable i set. Its pc1050 then when im done with that pc i change it to pc1051. These are remote computers in a building thats 2 minutes away from me. So in the link i gave $kenwhite it describes how there is a limit to the file path you can read with powershell. Well under that it describes how to increase the file path limit. I just did that today and the command deletes more files now but it hangs on this one, in the next comment.

\pc\c$\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\webview2\ed4f1133-4512-436f-85b1-4b3cb200274e_ADAL\2\EBWebView\Default\Service Worker\CacheStorage\571988c4897ef87c20ec4d6b13878cf6c36e1caf\c2f1e8f4-b6ef-4d69-ad7f-4ce2d5b9e722\index-dir

Have you tried using \\?\UNC\$pc\C$ as described at the link?

THANK YOU! That was it! When i first saw that mentioned i tried \?$pc\C$ .I assumed that UNC wouldn't let me reach a remote comuter but it did. Now I can just do one command, delete all. No renaming required. Thanks again!

@jorgegoogle, you are welcome. If you find that this is the best answer to the question (there is only one (1)), please select the check mark to indicate it. This is how SO works.

I will edit the answer to remove -Force from Get-ChildItem since this should probably not be done to the All Users, Default, or Default User directories. If you do want to delete directories, then remove the -File switch from Get-ChildItem and add -Recurse to Remove-Item.

I dont see a check mark next to ""Have you tried using \?\UNC$pc\C$ as described at the link? –
lit
1 hour ago""

@jorgegoogle, there is not a check mark on comments. There is an up triangle. The check mark it to the left of the answer, just below the up/down votecount.
